# Error (1093):You cant update target table for update in FROM Clause

Tags: mysql

**This is the select statement  which i have got the correct answer:**

```
select s_billing_cycle.Billing_cycle from s_billing_cycle 
join o_daily_lcsgeneration_copy on o_daily_lcsgeneration_copy.Location=s_billing_cycle.Location where o_daily_lcsgeneration_copy.Date between s_billing_cycle.From_Date and s_billing_cycle.To_Date
```

**while updating the same query into another table i couldnt do that using update query getting :
You cant update target table "o_daily_lcsgeneration_copy" for update in FROM Clause 
the query i have used is :**

```
update o_daily_lcsgeneration_copy  set o_daily_lcsgeneration_copy.Billing_cycle = (select s_billing_cycle.Billing_cycle from s_billing_cycle join o_daily_lcsgeneration_copy on o_daily_lcsgeneration_copy.Location=s_billing_cycle.Location where o_daily_lcsgeneration_copy.Date between s_billing_cycle.From_Date and s_billing_cycle.To_Date)
```

Help  me !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap it in a subquery (*thus creating temporary table*)

```
UPDATE  o_daily_lcsgeneration_copy
SET     o_daily_lcsgeneration_copy.Billing_cycle = 
(
    SELECT Billing_cycle
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  s_billing_cycle.Billing_cycle
        FROM    s_billing_cycle
                INNER JOIN o_daily_lcsgeneration_copy
                    ON o_daily_lcsgeneration_copy.Location = s_billing_cycle.Location
        WHERE   o_daily_lcsgeneration_copy.DATE BETWEEN s_billing_cycle.From_Date
                AND s_billing_cycle.To_Date
    ) s
)
```

or `JOIN` the tables

```
UPDATE  o_daily_lcsgeneration_copy a
        INNER JOIN s_billing_cycle b
            ON a.Location = b.Location
SET     a.Billing_cycle = b.Billing_cycle
WHERE   a.DATE BETWEEN b.From_Date AND b.To_Date
```